# InsertBatch in Sharding

Tags: mongodb

What is actually happening behind the scene with a big InsertBatch if 
one is writing to a sharded cluster? Does MongoDb actually support 
bulk insert or the InserBatch is actually inserting one at a time at 
the server level? How does this work with sharding then? Does this 
mean that a mongos will look at every item in the batch to figure out 
what is the shard key of each item and then will route it to the right 
server? This will break bulk insert if it exist and does not seem to 
be efficient. What is the mechanics of InsertBatch for a sharding 
solution? I am using version 2.0 and willing to upgrade if that makes any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulk inserts are an actual MongoDB feature and are (somewhat) more performant than seperate per-document inserts due to less roundtrips.

In a sharded environment if mongos receives a bulk insert it will figure out which part of the bulk has to be sent to which shard. There are no differences between 2.0 and 2.1 and it is the most efficient way to bulk insert data into a sharded database.

If you're curious to how exactly mongos works have a look at it's source code here :

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/s