# Handle massive amount of writes and horizontal scale

Tags: mongodb, bigdata, nosql

#### First let me explain what our data looks like:

As now we are using **mongodb** and have one collection with 10 fields and one compound index which will suffer lots of writes and **not so much reads**.

#### What is our experience with mongodb :

Because we are writing data in **chunks** of 1000 records and mongodb enable feature of writting data in chunks, that speeds up a process a lot so we were able to write **60k records/s** with no index and **45k records/s** with index.

#### And what is our problem then?

It doesn't scale horizontal very well. Mongodb has **sharding** feature but problem is that it is good for reading and if you have very big data. Because of fact that we will delete old data from collection it is not our main problem but writes are, and sharding actually slow down process as we can see because you cannot write in chunks (for every record mongos must decide in which shard to put it). Actually even if we make some 20k/seconds and have horizontal scale for writes it would be good but as many shard you put in cluster writing is getting slower so it is not so much of solution (as we can see).

#### My questions:

1. Is there any way to make mongo sharding to work well for our scenario? Maybe somehow tell mongos to put chunks (1000 records) in one shard. Maybe that would give us horizontal scale?
2. What other NoSql database you suggest for our problem?
3. Some other comments/solutions are welcome.

Comment: Keep in mind that MongoDB's feature is called *auto*-sharding. You can still do manual sharding if you already have a well working technique for it. Sure, that makes querying more complicated, but if those large chunks belong to each other in a logical sense, making the reads work by manually collecting the data from different servers should be very well possible. But that's just a vague idea, I guess there are better options.

Comment: Interesting idea. What do you mean by manual sharding? Is there any mongos 'config' where I can tell him to behave by some rules or I have to replace mongos by myself (code it). Problem is that I don't know if mongos sends every record separately or he is smart enough and sends them in chunk (use that mongo chunk write feature which is very fast) if he see that they all belong to one shard.

Comment: Sharding can be simple: if the user's last name starts with A-M, use db server1, else server2. Of course that grows complicated once you have to add a server, so that's what auto-sharding helps you with, essentially. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404173/insertbatch-in-sharding, batches will remain batches through `mongos`. Make sure you have enough data for mongodb to even *use* a second shard (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/), and make sure you have a shard key that allows *parallel writes* (i.e. not a monotonically increasing shard key)

Comment: I would suggest to append this data to raw file system. Hadoop is a popular and free distributed file system  it looks too complicated to store log files but it helps with processing tasks to read data.

Comment: the issue is possibly related to your choice of the shard key.  You don't mention how you sharded the collection - what shard key did you use?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to #2

You could look into Riak. All the nodes are equal, there is no central server, which means it scales horizontally incredibly well. You would be able to write different bits of information to each riak node in parallel, which should give you fast write speeds. If your riak cluster isn't fast enough, just add more nodes.

http://basho.com/riak/